# Show widget slowly by animation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget, which on click I'll show the other widget and on the second time it'll close. I need to add some animation so I can see the opening or closing. Right now it's just opening and closing very fast/immediately.

My code:

```
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 13, right: 13, top: 13),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                    spreadRadius: 2,
                    blurRadius: 3,
                    offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'DIAGNOSIS',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                                    fontFamily: 'PoppinsMedium',
                                    fontSize: 14),
                              ),
                              showB
                                  ? GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    print('false');
                                    setState(() {
                                      showB = false;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(
                                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_up_outlined))
                                  : GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    print('true');
                                    setState(() {
                                      showB = true;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Icon(
                                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_outlined))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        showB
                            ? Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                              child: Container(
                                width: Width * 0.9,
                                child: Divider(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8, top: 2),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [


                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 7, bottom: 5),
                                      child: Text('Diagnosis',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular', color: kPrimaryColor,)),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: Width * 0.92 ,
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        onChanged: (value) {

                                        },
                                        onSaved: (value) {},
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                                            fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
                                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                            icon: Icon(
                                              Icons.search_outlined,
                                              color: Color(0xffbdbdbd),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide:
                                            const BorderSide(color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), width: 1),
                                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                              const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide:
                                            const BorderSide(color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), width: 1),
                                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                              const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          filled: true,
                                          hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                                              color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
                                          hintText: "Enter Diagnosis",
                                          fillColor: Colors.white70,
                                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor, width: 1),
                                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                              const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 7, bottom: 5),
                                      child: Text('Comments',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,

                                          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular', color: kPrimaryColor,)),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: Width * 0.92 ,
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        maxLines: 5,// when user presses enter it will adapt to it
                                        onChanged: (value) {

                                        },
                                        onSaved: (value) {},
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15,
                                            color: kPrimaryColor,
                                            fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
                                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide:
                                            const BorderSide(color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), width: 1),
                                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                              const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide:
                                            const BorderSide(color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), width: 1),
                                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                              const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          filled: true,
                                          hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                                              color: Color(0xffbdbdbd), fontFamily: 'UbuntuRegular'),
                                          hintText: "Enter Comments",
                                          fillColor: Colors.white70,
                                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: const BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor, width: 1),
                                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                              const Radius.circular(10.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Align(
                                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight ,
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 13),
                                          child: Container(
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    color: kPrimaryColor,
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                              ),
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                                child: Icon(
                                                Icons.add,
                                                size: 25.0,
                                                color:Colors.white
                                          ),
                                              )
                                          ),
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 7, bottom: 5),
                                        child: RawMaterialButton(
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            print('sad');
                                            setState(() {
                                              showA = false;
                                              showB = false;
                                              showC = true;
                                              showD = false;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          elevation: 2.0,
                                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                                          child: Icon(
                                              Icons.check_outlined,
                                              size: 35.0,
                                              color:kPrimaryColor
                                          ),
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                                          shape: CircleBorder(),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )


                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                            : Container()
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I just want the container to open or close like a flick. So how can I add animation so that it will close or open a little slower or with some animation?

Comment: I have added an answer. Check out if it works for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an opinion based question. But one simple way to do this is to use `Implicit Animations` in Flutter.

For your case, you can use `AnimatedSize`.

First, add `with TickerProviderStateMixin` to your `State<T>` class definition.
For example like this,

```
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
```

Then, you have a your second child of the column is a `Column` like this

```
showB ? Column( ..... ) : Container()
```

Remove the conditional and the else case with `Container` and change it to this,

```
Column( ..... )
```

Now, wrap this `Column` inside an `AnimatedSize` and `Container` widgets like this,

```
AnimatedSize(
  vsync: this,
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
  child: Container(
    height: showB ? null : 0,
    child: Column( ..... ), // This is the same widget from above
  )
)
```

Now, your element should automatically be animating.

This code could be hard to follow, so check this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/BWFn36sv) for the full code.

Do note, I have remove the `kPrimaryColor` and `Width` variables since you have not provided them in code.

Check this gif to see how it is working.

[image]

Now, this is a very simplistic animation and you can definitely make it much better. Read more on [Implicit Animations in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/codelabs/implicit-animations).